# How to listen the close event of a modal in ngBootstrap and Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, angular2-observables

I'm trying to subscribe to the close event of a modal using ngbootstra, but I don't understand how it works. I have 2 components The 1st for lauching the modal and inside the 2nd one.

**the 1st**

**html**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>
```

**TS**

```
import { OtherComponent } from './../other/other.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-joker',
  templateUrl: './joker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./joker.component.scss']
})
export class JokerComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  open(): void{ 
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(OtherComponent, {centered: true});
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'Gerardo';
  }
}
```

**The 2nd**

**html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  templateUrl: './other.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other.component.scss']
})
export class OtherComponent {

  @Input() name: any;
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
  

}
```

But I don't know hoy to do the subscribe because it says that the close method is not an observable, also I like know how to emit any value when the modal is close in the 2nd component (2nd) Does some know how to do it?.

Btw is it necessary to do a unsubscribe?

Comment: Gerakt, the data you pass in clised is the argument of the function activeModal.close('Close click')`` . In this case is only a string, you can use in .ts, e.g. `this.activeModal.close({lastName:'lastName',firstName:'firstName'})` and get the value in the promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **OtherComponent**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="close()">Close</button>
    
    
    close() {
        this.activeModal.close("Send data")
      }
```

so you can subscribe this from parent component

In **JokerComponent**

```
    open(): void{ 
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(OtherComponent, {centered: true});
        modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data)
              if(data){
                  // you can check if the modal returns any data or not
              }
        })
      }
```

Comment: bro can I know where did you get the 'tempModal'. I couldnt find it in the documentation

Comment: @iwantcheeseburger tempModal should be replaced by modalRef. Basically we need to use the variable name which we've used to capture the open event from modalService. Sorry for the typo mistake

Answer (score 6):

You can access the `result` variable of your `modalRef`, as it returns a Promise, ie

```
modalRef.result.then((data) => {
  // on close
},
(error) => {
  // on error/dismiss
});
```

See the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api) for further information.

And the reason you cannot subscribe to the `close` method is that it returns void instead of an Observable (listed in the docs as well).

On a general note, personally I'd move the open and close methods to a service so your other component (the one supposed to be listening to the close event) can access the `modalRef` variable.

Comment: remember in promise use `then((data)=>{...},(error)=>{...})`. in ngb-bootstrap modal, is you use "dismiss" or close click outside, it's ejecuted the last part -the error-. If you don't mannage the error (you can do nothing, but you need declare), Angular give you an error